# Change Event Trigger is not available for FeedItem

Tags: platform-event, change-data-capture, pushtopic

I am trying to create a change event trigger for the feed item, it's not available for creation. For other objects it's available, but missing for feed item, FeedComment, and some other standard objects.?

I am expecting something like `FeedItem__ChangeEvent` in the dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in [This list here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_associated_objects_change_event.htm), Salesforce does not have Support for Change Data Capture on every single Standard Object. FeedItem is among those not mentioned.